# Saxon genitive to identify algorithms, methods, techniques, theorems,

Tags: saxon-genitive

When identifying an algorithm or theorem, which of these two sentences is preferred, *Seifert's algorithm* or *Seifert algorithm*? Does it have to do with the "prestige" of the algorithm/theorem? I mean that we conventionally say *Newton-Raphson method* and not *Newton-Raphson's method*, but it seems to me that when the method is not so known the possessives formed without an apostrophe 's appear to be preferred.

Comment: One name, use "'s". Two names, don't.

Comment: There are one-named ones without *'s*. :-/

Comment: References seem to call it *Seifert's algorithm* but the math leads to *Seifert surfaces*?

Comment: @Mitch The rule is intriguing. I've been searching some instances and it seems to work most of the times for two-named references. For instance, a search of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process in Google Books occurs almost always without the 's. But as bib and Neeku say, the rule is often broken in one-named instances.

Comment: @Neeku: Which ones? Algorithms seem to be all "-'s". This seems to call for a catalog of named mathematical objects to compare and classify.

Comment: @Mitch As an instance, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) is one of the one-worded ones without `'s`. There are more of them if you look at the links I've provided in the answer below. (:

Answer (score 2):

I think *apostrophe+s* is always preferred. I tried googling and checking [various](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan%27s_algorithm) [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamartino_method) in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms), and most of them use the saxon genitive, because they simply *belong* to the person. Even the Newton-Raphson one is also known as [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

I can't really explain why this inconsistency exists, but checking a few names in [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Shor%27s%20algorithm%2C%20Shor%20algorithm&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CShor%20%27s%20algorithm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CShor%20algorithm%3B%2Cc0), I'd say that "*'s*" is always preferred, since there's a big difference in results of the two forms.